# List only processes that are in suspended mode

Tags: suspend, process, ps

to list processes that are running in the background, one can type:
`ps -ef` or `ps -aux`

but how to list processes that are suspended, let's say I had some process in the foreground and just suspended (either with `bg <jobid>` or `Ctrl+z`)

how to I get to know what are the processes in that status (suspended)?

thanks

Answer (score 12):

The output of `ps` includes the status:

```
$ ps aux | head -n2
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0 200892  5132 ?        Ss   Mar04   0:20 /sbin/init
```

The `STAT` column is the state of the process. This can be one of (from `man ps`):

```
Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output
specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:

           D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
           R    running or runnable (on run queue)
           S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
           T    stopped by job control signal
           t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
           W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
           X    dead (should never be seen)
           Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
```

So, you are looking for processes whose state is shown as `T`. To see only those processes, you can parse the `ps` output for them:

```
ps aux | awk '$8=="T"'
```

Sometimes, additional characters can be added to the state field (depending on the options you use), so this might be a safer approach:

```
ps aux | awk '$8~/T/'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the bash `jobs` builtin to see the status of jobs that are backgrounded or suspended e.g.

- start and background one process; start and suspend a second with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

  ```
  $ sleep 100 & sleep 200
  [1] 12444
  ^Z
  [2]+  Stopped                 sleep 200
  ```
- check the status of all jobs

  ```
  $ jobs
  [1]-  Running                 sleep 100 &
  [2]+  Stopped                 sleep 200
  ```
- check the status of only suspended jobs

  ```
  $ jobs -s
  [2]+  Stopped                 sleep 200
  ```

See the `JOB CONTROL` section of `man bash`, or the shell's online help `help jobs`.

Comment: Unfortunately `jobs` lists only those processes started in the current shell (i.e., on the command line) so doesn't pick up any that were started by the system or login process, etc.